# Sign file with objective-c (ios/mac)

Tags: ios, macos, file, import, sign

My application create,export and import files, to know if an imported file is mine, i use an extension but this is not enough, so i add a string (as data) to the file to detect it, but again i think that is not the right way to do it.

can you tell me if there's a way on objective-c do that?

Comment: +1, interesting question, here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [Uniform Type Identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html).  The UTI mechanism provides the ability to identify different types of data based on different criteria.

Comment: as i know, UTI is to associate a file type with an application, like the 'open in' in ios and 'open with' in mac os. but i'm creating a new 'type' of file, my app have to check if it is the creator of this file before begin the treatment.

Comment: can i create a mime type and set it in my file? if yes how can i extract it after importing the file?

Comment: @MalekRadhouani Sorry I don't know; the docs seem to imply that you can use a MIME-type mechanism but I've never actually done it myself.